# SOes y la publicidad de afiliados

Tags: soporte

Todo esto parte de la publicación en MSE *[Affiliate Ads Are Coming To The Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306737/304899)*, en donde se explica que están extendiendo la publicidad a la mayoría de los sitios graduados o, mejor dicho, que ya se extendió pero que, por falta de contenido específico para el sitio, no están mostrando nada. En nuestro caso, no es necesario más de dos dedos de frente para entender que se resume en: hasta ahora no se buscó proactivamente que los clientes interesados en publicitar en zonas donde se habla español entreguen contenido localizado.

Citando una frase de [Nueve Reinas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nueve_reinas): [...lo que faltan son financistas](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0247586/quotes/qt2350609).

La pregunta inmediata: **¿SOes va a empezar a tener publicidad?**
Sería interesante saber si este nuevo paso de SO se aplica a nuestro sitio, y cómo; qué deberíamos esperar en la interfaz, y a qué estar atentos, especialmente siguiendo los esfuerzos de localización. También está claro que esto [no nos va a cambiar nada](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) a la mayoría de los que estamos leyendo Meta, sino que aplica a usuarios nuevos o no registrados, usuarios ocasionales del sitio que caen por una búsqueda en Google. En la publicación en MSE se habla de mínimos que un sitio tiene que cumplir para mostrar los anuncios, y SOes los cumple. Lo que no queda claro es si aplica en un sitio en español.

Lo que mata es la ansiedad, así que abrí una ventana de incógnito (Chrome 63), sin iniciar sesión, sin Ad Blockers, para encontrarme con esto:

> [image: espacio en blanco antes de la pregunta]

Un espacio en blanco, repetido 2 veces en todas las publicaciones que revisé. Está claro que es el lugar donde van los anuncios, pero si no hay ninguno ¿hace falta que quede ese espacio horrible ahí? Porque la verdad es que lo hace ver como un sitio con un diseño poco profesional.

Espero que sea algo momentáneo, mientras están implementando algo ahora, y de lo que están al tanto, pero si no, lo puedo publicar como bug acá o en MSE.

Y después me pregunté si [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) no tenía ya publicidad de alguna campaña que apunte a público en español. De nuevo, incógnito, sin iniciar sesión, cambié el Accept Language a 100% español exclusivamente, desde una IP de Argentina, y chan!!! Estos son algunos de los varios anuncios que vi:

> [image: Una publicidad de J.P.Morgan]
>   [image: Otra publicidad de J.P.Morgan]
>   [image: De nuevo, una más de J.P.Morgan]
>   [image: Y adivinen qué?.. Sí, es un anuncio de J.P.Morgan]
>   [image: Bueno, ya no tengo que decirles qué es esto... Pero sólo por si acaso no quedó claro, es otra publicidad más de J.P.Morgan]

Anuncios de J.P.Morgan a donde quiera que vaya. En todas las preguntas, todas, absolutamente todas a las que entré, tenían publicidad de J.P.Morgan... El nombre J.P.Morgan aparece escrito más veces que Stack Overflow. Tanto, que un visitante imprudente diría que es la web de preguntas y respuestas de los desarrolladores de J.P.Morgan.

¿No es esto algo que querríamos evitar? Que aparezca siempre el mismo afiliado en la publicidad, en todas las publicaciones me parece contraproducente. Creo que convendría poner algún filtro en los casos donde haya solamente 1 (o pocos) pautando -que perfectamente podría ser el caso de SOes en un inicio.

**Resumiendo:**

- Me gustaría confirmar si SOes forma parte de esos sitios. Y si es así:

  - Ver si es necesario arreglar lo del espacio en blanco.

Y además,

- Dar como feedback que hay casos donde hay una única publicidad, repetida constantemente, que me parece contraproducente para SE.

---

> Nota: no me parece para nada mal que haya publicidad. -Hasta quizás ayude a que sea más sencillo para SO dedicar recursos a los sitios internacionales de esta forma ;-) **Pero** no emití juicio de valor en la pregunta intencionalmente, y me interesa que esto se mantenga así en cualquier comentario o respuesta. No me interesa  discutir si esto es bueno o malo. Mi idea es que, si se implementa, se haga de la mejor forma posible.

Comment: Wow. Vi el anuncio de la publicidad pero no me esperaba tanta como tu comentas. En cuanto a nuestro sitio, supongo que llegará y de ser así, ¿quien tiene el *poder* para limitar su cantidad? ¿ El community Manager?

Comment: Si, creo que te había entendido. Me refería por ejemplo a _Ver si es necesario arreglar lo del espacio en blanco._ Eso podría reportarse a StackExchange, pero se podría hacer algo en [es.so]? En cuanto a lo segundo, puede reportarse, pero dudo que hagan algo. Si un afiliado paga por que su publicidad aparezca en todas las páginas, me temo que así sera ;)

Comment: @Pikoh ok. En cuanto al espacio en blanco, en MSE piden que el feedback sea en el Meta de cada sitio. Empiezo por acá y veo si es necesario publicar en MSE... En cuanto a una publicidad repetida excesivamente, creo que sí se puede hacer algo. Un afiliado paga por una cierta frecuencia, pero no para estar en todas las páginas todo el tiempo. En definitiva, creo que está mal. Es mi opinión, pueden tomarla o no. Pero opiniones fue lo que pidieron.

Comment: @Mariano vale, ahora si entendí, pidieron el feedback aqui. Por mi parte, estoy de acuerdo contigo en todo.

Comment: yo entendi que en cada meta se discutia si una publicidad correspondia o no al sitio. Y en MSE se discutian problemas como estos. Voy a releer el post entonces. Mas alla de esta publicacion, lo del espacio en blanco si deberia ir alla.

Comment: @gbianchi puede ser, pero creo que la primera pregunta, enfocada en la localización, es específica de SOes... lo del espacio en blanco sin duda, pero me pareció prudente publicar primero acá para ver que no estuviese diciendo una burrada antes de escalarlo

Comment: @lois6b El poder lo tienes tu. No estás obligado a ver los anuncios.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos y también elijo no ver la televisión por la publicidad y sigo pensando que es demasiada. Qué no la vea no hace que me parezca bien tanta publicidad

Comment: ufff, esto es un bug. Bah, son dos bugs. El espacio en blanco lo veo mismo en Stack Overflow (porque se ve que a JPMorgan no le interesan developers de Uruguay). Seguís viendo JPMorgan en todos lados? lo reportaría como bug en MSE. La idea es que los ads tienen que ser útiles... y mostrar JPMorgan por todos lados no le hace bien ni a Stack Overflow ni a JPMorgan

Comment: @g3rv4 desde que empezaron los cambios en el diseño por Teams, vi contenido un poco más variado (no mucho -JP Morgan, IBM, Microsoft y rara vez algún otro), pero varía mucho dependiendo de dónde me conecte ("*o del clima*" :-)), y puede repetirse esto de ver 1 solo. Pero por más que vea a algún otro anunciante, me sigue dando la sensacion de que son demasiados del mismo, todos diciendo lo mismo... Mi idea era publicarlo primero acá y llevarlo a MSE si no se tomaba acción por el canal formal (mod -> CM -> SO)... Supongo que lo voy a publicar cuando encuentre algo de tiempo (días complicados),

Comment: @Mariano por acá podemos llevar lo del espacio en blanco (ya que no tenemos publicidades todavía). El lugar para reportar lo de SO sería MSO. Si tenés un screenshot con JPMorgan por todos lados (idealmente de la página completa) mejor. Si no querés hacer el post a MSO, mandame el screenshot por mail y veo qué me dicen por acá

Comment: @g3rv4 sí, tenés razón. Acá lo estaba planteando como preocupación a futuro, o por si ya estaba pasando y yo no lo veía (ni idea del estado de implementación de Ads)... Y para ver la respuesta que obtenía. Pero si decís que toman lo del espacio, genial, publico sólo lo de la frecuencia (creo que en MSE, entiendo que aplica a toda la red, por ejemplo ahora sólo veo de IBM en SU, corregime cualquier cosa).

Comment: Esto lo he reportado pero no he recibido respuesta todavía.  Seguiré intentando pero como se lo imaginan, la publicidad seguirá a todos los sitios de la red.  Esto es decisión de la empresa.

Comment: @JuanM por supuesto, la intención no es quitar publicidad sino que la web se vea profesional, como lo es (sin un espacio en blanco). Muchísimas gracias por seguir el tema!

Comment: @Mariano ¡exacto! Esa es la idea. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yo coincido con la respuesta que ha dado Jose Antonio Dura Olmos, en SOen hay anuncios de trabajo a la derecha que veo más interesante que un anuncio comercial, también generarían ingresos a SOes, ¿Para qué anuncios comerciales pudiendo tener anuncios sobre puestos de trabajo?.

Al fin y al cabo, si encuentro un trabajo gracias a ese anuncio, me beneficia a mi, a SO y al recuiter, sin embargo, un anuncio comercial solo incita a comprar algo que no necesitas, porque si lo necesitares, lo hubieses buscado tú y no te hubieses esperado a verlo en un anuncio.

Answer (score 0):

Seguiré usando uBlock Origin y un fichero de hosts para filtrar anuncios comerciales.

No todo el mundo piensa que el pago monetario de X a SO es motivo suficiente para que Y vea la "información" siembre sesgada y frecuentemente manipuladora de X mientras usa SO. Si su información fuese realmente útil y relevante al sitio podrían ponerla como una respuesta o pregunta.

Aunque no me corresponde elegir en qué se convierte SO sí puedo elegir qué leo, qué veo, qué ejecuto en mi ordenador. Los anuncios comerciales van contra eso. Me alegra que me permitáis usar este sitio que es por lo demás estupendo con un bloqueador de anuncios. Antes dejaría de usar SO, como he hecho con otros sitios que activamente prohíben estos bloqueadores, que ver anuncios comerciales.

Ojalá os vaya bien.

Answer (score 0):

Incluso Google tiene un imperfecto historial a la hora de filtrar software malicioso de los anuncios que sirve. (Por ejemplo [recientement YouTube estaba sirviendo anuncios de minería do monedas criptográficas (en inglés)](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/01/27/cryptojackers_slip_coinhive_mining_code_into_doubleclick_ads/))

- ¿Que medidas van a tomar para evitar tener que filtrar a mano anuncios que esconden Javascript malicioso?
- ¿El contenido Javascript que se sirve como parte de los anuncios va ha ser albergado en los dominos de Stack Exchange?

Esto es una traducción de [una respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306762/348498) de [Peter Taylor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/164922/peter-taylor)