# Diseño de la página de una pregunta deja espacio en blanco

Tags: bug

Comparado con SO normal, el sitio en español deja un GRAN espacio en blanco entre el título y el contenido de la pregunta para todas las preguntas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sé que no afecta la funcionalidad de nada y sólo obliga a hacer scroll. Igual, ¿se puede hacer algo para ajustarlo?

Comment: Es por los anuncios de publicidad, se habló de algo al respecto en [SOes y la publicidad de afiliados](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3148/soes-y-la-publicidad-de-afiliados)

Comment: Gracias, @KacosPro. Busqué esta información por varios términos pero no la encontré (y hace mucho no veo ads en SO en inglés, así que no lo recordaba). Si lo pones como respuesta, lo marco como aceptado; si lo quieren cerrar como duplicado, también estará bien :)

Comment: A mi no me parece que sea un duplicado, y según lo hablado en los comentarios sí es un bug. Esperemos a ver que dice la comunidad al respecto :)

Comment: Yo tampoco lo considero un duplicado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podría decirse que no se trata de un bug sino de una característica de la cual se habla en [SOes y la publicidad de afiliados](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3148/65) la cual aparentemente no ha sido del todo implementada.

Los usuarios con 200 puntos de reputación o más tienen el privilegio "[reduce ads](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads)" (curiosamente falta traducir) por lo cual Ale y otros usuarios como él no ven el espacio en blanco.

Los usuarios anónimos o con menos de 200 puntos de reputación en algún momento podrán ver anuncios pero en estos momentos parece ser que la mayoría su lugar ven espacios en blanco.

Answer (score -2):

No creo que sea un bug, dejo una captura de pantalla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Recomiendo que antes de hacer un reporte hagas un `cross browser testing` para descartar que sea un tema de navegador u otro factor

Comment: Esta no es una respuesta y, si se necesita aclarar algo como "qué navegador(es) usé", un comentario es suficiente.

Comment: @Alfabravo: Meta funciona un poco diferente al sitio principal. Me parece valido haber publicado una respuesta para incluir una captura de pantalla.